# Updating list of dictionaries within react state

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an input form with two buttons to either remove the entire input line, or add a new line below.

Adding a new input line is working, but removing the input line is not working correctly. There is some odd behaviour. For example, pressing the remove button causes the final elements to be removed instead of the item in the list with the correct id.

I've tried to create a complete minimal example below, using the best reactish style I know.

Please advise what my be causing the remove feature to be removing the wrong elements.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const App = () => {

    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    const addItem = () => {
        const newItem = new Map();
        newItem.id = uuidv4();
        newItem.field = "";
        newItem.addButton = <Button onClick={() => addItem()}>Add</Button>;
        newItem.removeButton = <Button onClick={() => removeItem(newItem.id)}>Remove</Button>;

        setList(prevList => {
            return prevList.concat(newItem);
        });
    };

    useEffect( () => {
        addItem();
    }, []);

    const removeItem = (id) => {
        setList(prevList => {
            return prevList.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
          {React.version}
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Field</td>
                <td>Add Button</td>
                <td>Remove Button</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {list.map(item => (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td><input id={item.id} type="text"/></td>
                    <td>{item.addButton}</td>
                    <td>{item.removeButton}</td>
                  </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    );

};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem seems to be missing `key` so React is unable to track elements properly:

```
{list.map(item => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
```

Another problem is that mutating the array in following code. This can have unexpected side effects:

```
setList(prevList => {
   return prevList.concat(newItem);
});
```

Best practice is to always create new state:

```
setList(prevList => {
   return [...prevList, newItem];
});
```

[image: Edit thirsty-tereshkova-9so82]

Comment: This is extremely helpful to know. It solved my issue. Do I need to put a key on any element that should be updated when the state changes?